# How hard is it to find a spring network configuration with the lowest energy?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, optimization

Given a [spring system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_system):

[image]

where the total tension between the nodes should be minimized, it seems possible that a physics simulation of this graph does not arrive at the lowest energy state, getting stuck in a local minimum instead.

Is finding a positioning of nodes that achieves the lowest energy NP-hard?

Comment: The problem is still not clear to me. What is input of the problem? How positioning of the nodes change the tension between nodes? Please elaborate.